# Deserialize JSON from API response

Tags: c#, json, serialization, prtg

I am using an API called "PRTG" that is a server monitoring service. After making a call for all sensors on a device, I get this response in Fiddler:

```
{
"prtg-version": "14.2.10.2114",
"treesize": 6,
"sensors": [
    {
        "objid": 6277,
        "probe": "Koneo Kalmar AB",
        "group": "Koneo Kalmar home",
        "device": "bl0615.systempartner.local",
        "sensor": "Disk Space",
        "status": "Up",
        "status_raw": 3,
        "message": "<div class=\"status\">OK<div class=\"moreicon\"></div></div>",
        "message_raw": "OK",
        "lastvalue": "21 %",
        "lastvalue_raw": 21.0000,
        "priority": 4,
        "favorite": "<span class=\"objectisnotfavorite icon-gray ui-icon ui-icon-flag\" id=\"fav-6277\" onclick=\"_Prtg.objectTools.faveObject.call(this,6277,&apos;toggle&apos;);return false;\"></span>",
        "favorite_raw": 0
    },
    {
        "objid": 6279,
        "probe": "Koneo Kalmar AB",
        "group": "Koneo Kalmar home",
        "device": "bl0615.systempartner.local",
        "sensor": "PING",
        "status": "Up",
        "status_raw": 3,
        "message": "<div class=\"status\">OK<div class=\"moreicon\"></div></div>",
        "message_raw": "OK",
        "lastvalue": "0 msec",
        "lastvalue_raw": 0.0000,
        "priority": 5,
        "favorite": "<span class=\"objectisnotfavorite icon-gray ui-icon ui-icon-flag\" id=\"fav-6279\" onclick=\"_Prtg.objectTools.faveObject.call(this,6279,&apos;toggle&apos;);return false;\"></span>",
        "favorite_raw": 0
    },
    {
        "objid": 6280,
        "probe": "Koneo Kalmar AB",
        "group": "Koneo Kalmar home",
        "device": "bl0615.systempartner.local",
        "sensor": "DNS",
        "status": "Up",
         "status_raw": 3,
        "message": "<div class=\"status\">OK: 127.0.0.1<div class=\"moreicon\"></div></div>",
        "message_raw": "OK: 127.0.0.1",
        "lastvalue": "0 msec",
        "lastvalue_raw": 0.0000,
        "priority": 3,
        "favorite": "<span class=\"objectisnotfavorite icon-gray ui-icon ui-icon-flag\" id=\"fav-6280\" onclick=\"_Prtg.objectTools.faveObject.call(this,6280,&apos;toggle&apos;);return false;\"></span>",
        "favorite_raw": 0
    },
    {
        "objid": 6799,
        "probe": "Koneo Kalmar AB",
        "group": "Koneo Kalmar home",
        "device": "bl0615.systempartner.local",
         "sensor": "Disk Free: C:\\ Label:  Serial Number 34fe9d97", "status": "Up", "status_raw": 3,
        "message": "<div class=\"status\">OK<div class=\"moreicon\"></div></div>",
        "message_raw": "OK",
        "lastvalue": "21 %",
        "lastvalue_raw": 21.2458,
        "priority": 3,
        "favorite": "<span class=\"objectisnotfavorite icon-gray ui-icon ui-icon-flag\" id=\"fav-6799\" onclick=\"_Prtg.objectTools.faveObject.call(this,6799,&apos;toggle&apos;);return false;\"></span>",
        "favorite_raw": 0
    },
    {
        "objid": 6800,
        "probe": "Koneo Kalmar AB",
        "group": "Koneo Kalmar home",
        "device": "bl0615.systempartner.local",
         "sensor": "Disk Free: D:\\ Label:DATA  Serial Number 44bc0bc3", "status": "Up",
        "status_raw": 3,
        "message": "<div class=\"status\">OK<div class=\"moreicon\"></div></div>",
        "message_raw": "OK",
        "lastvalue": "49 %",
        "lastvalue_raw": 49.4901,
        "priority": 3,
        "favorite": "<span class=\"objectisnotfavorite icon-gray ui-icon ui-icon-flag\" id=\"fav-6800\" onclick=\"_Prtg.objectTools.faveObject.call(this,6800,&apos;toggle&apos;);return false;\"></span>",
        "favorite_raw": 0
    },
    {
        "objid": 6801,
        "probe": "Koneo Kalmar AB",
        "group": "Koneo Kalmar home",
        "device": "bl0615.systempartner.local",
         "sensor": "SNMP HP Proliant System Health 1", "status": "Warning", "status_raw": 4,
        "message": "<div class=\"status\">Warning in Disk Controller Status: &#39;Degraded&#39;<div class=\"moreicon\"></div></div>",
        "message_raw": "Warning in Disk Controller Status: &apos;Degraded&apos;",
        "lastvalue": "2 #",
        "lastvalue_raw": 2.0000,
        "priority": 3,
        "favorite": "<span class=\"objectisnotfavorite icon-gray ui-icon ui-icon-flag\" id=\"fav-6801\" onclick=\"_Prtg.objectTools.faveObject.call(this,6801,&apos;toggle&apos;);return false;\"></span>",
        "favorite_raw": 0 
    }
]
}
```

I've tried to create a class structure that follows this response. It looks like this:

```
public class BasePrtgSensors
{
    [JsonProperty("prtg-version")]
    public string PrtgVersion { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("sensors")]
    public Dictionary<string, PrtgSensor> Sensors { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("treesize")]
    public string TreeSize { get; set; }
}

public class PrtgSensor
{
    [JsonProperty("objid")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("probe")]
    public string Probe { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("group")]
    public string Group { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("device")]
    public string Device { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("sensor")]
    public string Sensor { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("status_raw")]
    public string StatusRaw { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("message_raw")]
    public string MessageRaw { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("lastvalue")]
    public string LastValue { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("lastvalue_raw")]
    public string LastValueRaw { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("priority")]
    public string Priority { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("favorite")]
    public string Favorite { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("favorite_raw")]
    public string FavoriteRaw { get; set; }
}
```

I'm running this code:

```
protected T Execute<T>(string urlSegment)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(Client().DownloadString(_baseUrl + '/' + urlSegment.TrimStart('/')));
    }
```

It's a base method that's in my WebClient Wrapper that runs the url-query and tries to deserialize it into the class I choose (BasePrtgSensors).
The actual call is this:

```
public BasePrtgSensors GetSensors(string id)
    {
        return Execute<BasePrtgSensors>(_resultType + _contentSensors + _output + _columnsSensors + "&id=" + id + _auth);
    }
```

All I'm getting from my object is null and 0 values after the call.
I am pretty sure that I've screwed up somewhere in the class-structure, but I'm completely new to serialization and I can't seem to find why the response won't deserialize into my class.

Thanks in advance for any guidance!

Comment: Could it be the problem with your `BasePrtgSensors` class that has a `Dictionary<string, PrtgSensor>`? The Json does only have an array there.

Comment: At first, I don't know `JsonConvert`. According to the docs I would expect the default serializer settings to cause problems. They say that they apply to methods of `JsonConvert`. Maybe the default settings doesn't check your `[fieldName]` annotations and expects field names starting with an upper case letter. Try to create a serializer manually or change the default settings. However, do you have any exception message we could use to find the problem?

Comment: @SebastianSchlicht It actually does. JsonConvert is the default way to deserialize Json in Json.net. I've tested this with his code. See my answer. There should actually be an exception. At least I got one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just tested it myself with your code there. I get an exception when using it like so, because of the `Dictionary<string, PrtgSensor>`.

But, like I said in my comment, if you use a `List<PrtgSensor>` instead, I get everything into one `BasePrtgSensors` object.

The reason is, that `sensors` in json is an array or a list. A dictionary is always a key value pair.

Comment: Aha, I will definitly try making it a List.  I myself don't get any exceptions when running this code. I did get one when I tried to connect with https though.

Comment: I only took the json you provided. Could well be, that what you get through the webservice is empty and thus just a default instance of your class. (not sure here) At the very least, I could deserialize the provided string.